Reading from stdout blocks using subprocess
new.py
print("Gib number")
x = input()
print('numba is ', x)

launcher.py
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(['python', 'new.py'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT, stdin=sp.PIPE, text=True)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print('line is', line)
    p.stdin.write('10')


p.wait()

Why can't the launcher.py read from new.py's stdout on second iteration?
However, If I use pwntools to launch the same file, it succeeds, albeit with an error on sendline on second iteration, which is understandable because presumably the stdin of the new.py is closed by then.
_launcher.py
from pwn import process

p = process(['python', 'new.py'], stderr=process.PTY, stdout=process.PTY)

while True:
    output = p.recv()
    print('line is', output)
    p.sendline(10)  # Sends the answer with a newline


p.wait()

What mechanism does pwntools's recv and sendline use and how can I launch the new.py without having to use pwntools?
Please provide any relevant readings as well.

@SIGHUP please elaborate more on 'Try writing to the pipe before reading the response.' I am in fact trying to get the subprocess module to work

new.py expects to read a number, then write a number. launcher.py tries to read a number from new.py before you give it a number. Further, you try to do this multiple times, but new.py doesn't loop: it reads one, writes one, then exits.

@chepner, "launcher.py tries to read a number from new.py before you give it a number", my understanding is that the first .readline() reads 'Gib number', the stdin.write() after that should supply the number. Furthermore, on second iteration, it should read 'numba is {number}'. Shouldn't it?

Sorry, yes, I was focused on the input and output, ignoring the prompt.

One simple issue: input tries to read until a newline character is read; p.stdin.write, unlike print, does not write an implicit newline. Try p.stdin.write('10\n'), or print('10', file=p.stdin). p.sendline sounds like it does write a newline (or else the method would probably just be called p.send)

I added a newline character. No effect.

Output from new.py will be buffered by default, since it's writing to a pipe rather than terminal. Add flush=True to the print() call.
